# Determine the value of $a$ for which the function is continuous at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Determine the value of $a$ for which the function is continuous at $x=0$
>   $$
> f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> a \sin\frac{\pi}{2}(x+1) & \text{if} \ x\le0, \\ \\
> \frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3} &\text{if} \ x\gt0. \ 
> \end{cases}
> $$

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{x^3}$ begs for L'Hopital's rule.  You'll need to apply it three times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^3}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sin x}x\cdot\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}\cdot\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac1{\cos x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}  \text{ as }\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1=\lim_{x\to0}\cos x$$

$$=\frac12\left(\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\sin \frac x2}{\frac x2}\right)^2\text{ as }\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y$$

$$=\frac12$$

$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\sin\left(\frac\pi2(x+1)\right)=1$$

Now use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions).

Comment: @Tsotsi, what does it mean?

Comment: @Tsotsi, I forgot what you wrote either. But why don't you use a lingua franca.

Comment: How did the second one become 1?

Comment: @chndn, put $x=0$

Comment: @chndn, put $y=\frac x2,$ as $x\to0,y\to0$

Comment: @chndn,  Applying L'Hosiptal's Rule, $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x}2=\frac12$$

Comment: sorry I got it I was wrong ... +1

Answer (score -1):

**Hint** $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ if and only if

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)=f(0) \,.$$

Now $f(0)=a \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=??$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) =\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\tan(x)-\sin(x)}{x^3}=???$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) =\lim_{x \to 0^-}a \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}(x+1))=???$$

Comment: @chndn Then you should had included this in your problem. What don't you know?